# Identify selected option in Angular Material autocomplete component

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there any way to identify which option is selected in the autocomplete component so that when the user presses tab, I select the option instead of changing the focus of the field.

Here's my code:

```html
<div class="search-box">
  <i class="material-icons">search</i>
  <input #inputText 
    mdInput 
    [mdAutocomplete]="issuingAsset" 
    [attr.maxlength]="15" 
    [(ngModel)]="assetSearch" 
    (input)="inputText.value=$event.target.value.toUpperCase()"
    (keydown.tab)="onSearchByAsset()"
    (keyup)="onAutoCompletAsset(assetSearch)">
    <md-autocomplete #issuingAsset="mdAutocomplete" >
      <div>
        <md-option
        (onSelectionChange)="selectAsset(asset.symbol)"
        *ngFor="let asset of filteredAssets" 
        [value]="asset.symbol">
          <div class="text-auto-complete"> {{ asset.symbol}} - {{asset.company}}</div>
        </md-option>
    </div>
  </md-autocomplete>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey mate, please paste some code with your question.

Comment: Hello, my code: https://pastebin.com/pAbzfPEG

Comment: I see you are using an old version of material, md is now mat... cant you upgrade to the new version so you can implement my answer?

Comment: unfortunately not because the project is too big.

Comment: @BrendowAlmeida But you should be able to use `mat-switcher`. See this package on NPM for more info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-prefix-updater

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not paste any code, ill share an example I just worked with...

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" #selectFilter [(ngModel)]="concept" name="concept" placeholder="Concept" aria-label="Concept" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let concept of conceptsArrFiltered" [value]="concept.Id">
        {{ concept.Id }} - {{ concept.Desc }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

So the selected value will be held in this.concept since that is where ngModel binds to `[(ngModel)]="concept"` and we assign this value when we do `[value]="concept.Id"`.

Im not sure if this answers your question... did I get you right?

Comment: However it did not work because when I press TAB it does not select the field that I selected with the down arrow, it only changes focus and closes the autocomplete's combobox.